# Gdk::Pixbuf does not load images

Tags: c++, gtk, gdk, gdkpixbuf

I'm trying to load a *.jpg image into a Gdk:: Pixbuf, but it fails and keeps telling me: Error interpreting JPEG image file (Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80)

```
try{
    Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file(".../Test.jpg");
}
    catch(const Glib::FileError& ex) {
    std::cerr << "FileError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
    catch(const Gdk::PixbufError& ex) {
    std::cerr << "PixbufError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

The only installed versions are libjpeg8 and libjpeg8-dev

I have a similar problem loading *.png images: GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.
PixbufError: Failed to load image '.../Test.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file

The libpng versions are 12-dev and 12-0

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877330/django-os-x-wrong-jpeg-library-version-library-is-80-caller-expects-62-sorl-th

Comment: Is is this an Unbuntu (or debian based system)?  Is `libjpeg-turbo` also installed? What's the output of `ls /usr/lib/libjpeg*`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and libjpeg-turbo8 and libjpeg-turbo8-dev are installed.

ls /usr/lib/libjpeg* doesn't list anything, but 
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg* does and it says:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Just really to make sure, can you post the result of:

```
dpkg -l | grep libjpeg
```

Besides that, do you have the freeimage library installed?

```
dpkg -l | grep libfreeimage
```

If so, give it try to remove this package and try your code again.

Did this help?

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep libjpeg:`

ii  libjpeg-turbo8:amd64                      1.3.0-0ubuntu1                             amd64        IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ii  libjpeg-turbo8:i386                       1.3.0-0ubuntu1                             i386         IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ii  libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64                  1.3.0-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Development files for the IJG JPEG library

Comment: ii  libjpeg8:amd64                            8c-2ubuntu8                                amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg8:i386                             8c-2ubuntu8                                i386         Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg8-dev:amd64                        8c-2ubuntu8                                amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep libfreeimage` 

ii  libfreeimage-dev                          3.15.1-2build1                             amd64        Support library for graphics image formats (development files)
ii  libfreeimage3                             3.15.1-2build1                             amd64        Support library for graphics image formats (library)

Removing libfreeimage did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The filename looks strange, there's one dot ore than expected.
Use "../Test.jpg" instead of ".../Test.jpg".

And check your file really *is* a jpeg and not a png renamed as jpeg. `file ../Test.jpg` should tell you that.

Comment: The filenmae is not the probleme, I forgot to mention that I shortened it for this question.

The Image was created using gimp and I saved it as an jpeg and as an png, both cannot be read from the pixbuf.